# El problema del caballo en un tablero 4 x 3

Tags: python, algoritmos, recursión

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola, el problema consiste en un caballo que puede moverse 3 casillas en L.
La funcion debe recibir el numero de movimientos a hacer, y devolver el numero de movidas validas, por ejemplo si son 2 movimientos, podre ir primero del 0 al 6, o del 0 al 4, ahi ya hice un movimiento en el que hay dos posibilidades validas, entonces me queda otro movimiento, primero partiendo del 6, 6 al 0, 6 al 7 o 6 al 1 lo que hacen 3 movimientos validos mas, y por ultimo partiendo del 4 puedo ir del 4 al 3, 4 al 9 o 4 al 0 que son otros 3 movimientos validos, y ya gaste mis dos movimientos entonces ahi para el caso de inicio del 0, ese caso entonces tendra 8 movimientos validos en total, luego tendre que evaluar el caso del 1, hasta llegar al 9 y sumar todos esos movimientos que en total deberian ser 44.

El programa propuesto es:

```
chessBoard = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6], [7,8,9], [None, 0, None]]

def countMatrizElements(matriz):
 counter = 0
 for row in range(len(matriz)):
  for col in range (len(matriz[row])):
      if matriz[row][col] != None:
          counter = counter + 1
 return counter

def horseValidMovementsAux(board, movements, startpoint):
    if movements == 0:
        return 0
    for row in range(len(board)):
        for col in range (len(board[row])):
            if(board[row][col] == startpoint):
                if(row==0 and col == 0):
                   return 2+horseValidMovementsAux(board,movements-1,board[row+1][col+2])+horseValidMovementsAux(board,movements-1,board[row+2][col+1])
                elif(row==1 and col == 0):
                    return 3+horseValidMovementsAux(board,movements-1,board[row+1][col+2])+horseValidMovementsAux(board,movements-1,board[row-1][col+2])+horseValidMovementsAux(board,movements-1,board[row+2][col+1])
                elif(row==2 and col == 0):
                    return 2+horseValidMovementsAux(board,movements-1,board[row-1][col+2])+horseValidMovementsAux(board,movements-1,board[row-2][col+1])
                elif(row== 3 and col == 1):
                    return 2+horseValidMovementsAux(board,movements-1,board[row-2][col+1])+horseValidMovementsAux(board,movements-1,board[row-2][col-1])
                elif(row==0 and col == 1):
                   return 2+horseValidMovementsAux(board,movements-1,board[row+2][col+1])+horseValidMovementsAux(board,movements-1,board[row+2][col-1])
                elif(row==1 and col == 1):
                    return 0
                elif(row==2 and col == 1):
                    return 2+horseValidMovementsAux(board,movements-1,board[row-2][col+1])+horseValidMovementsAux(board,movements-1,board[row-2][col-1])
                elif(row==0 and col == 2):
                   return 2+horseValidMovementsAux(board,movements-1,board[row+2][col-1])+horseValidMovementsAux(board,movements-1,board[row+1][col-2])
                elif(row==1 and col == 2):
                    return 3+horseValidMovementsAux(board,movements-1,board[row+2][col-1])+horseValidMovementsAux(board,movements-1,board[row-1][col-2])+horseValidMovementsAux(board,movements-1,board[row+1][col-2])
                elif(row==2 and col == 2):
                    return 2+horseValidMovementsAux(board,movements-1,board[row-2][col-1])+horseValidMovementsAux(board,movements-1,board[row-1][col-2])
                                

def horseValidMovements(board, movements):
 countingMovements = 0
 for startPosition in range(countMatrizElements(board)):
   countingMovements = countingMovements + horseValidMovementsAux(board, movements, startPosition)
 return countingMovements

print(horseValidMovements(chessBoard, 1))
```

Que al llamar con 1 movimiento me da en total 20 posibilidades, lo cual es correcto. Pero cuando llamo con 2 movimientos me da 66, que esta mal, porque se supone que con 2 movimientos deberia dar 46.

Analizando el programa paso a paso me encuentro con esto:

Ingreso 2 movimientos
startposition es 0

cuando llamo a la funcion recursiva le paso 2 movimientos y la casilla 0

ingresa al for que buscara en donde esta mi elemento. lo encuentra en la fila 3 columna 1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

suma 2, resta un movimiento, haciendo que de 2 movimientos ahora solo le quede 1 movimiento, llama primero a la casilla de la fila 1 con la columna 0, osea el 4 y tambien llama a la casilla de la fila 1 con la columna 2, osea la casilla 6.

ahora, cuando llama al elemento 4 estara en la fila 1 con columna 0
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que pasara aquí es que sumara 3, y llamara a los demas pero como ahora sus movimientos son 1, al restar en la llamada seran 0 y activaran el caso base haciendo que no se sume mas y retorne finalmente su suma

Lo mismo para el caso de la casilla 6, que esta en la fila 1 columna 2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

sumara 3 y hara sus llamadas que activaran el caso base.

En total con las sumas tendriamos 2+3+3 = 8
Lo esperado seria: el 0 puede ir al 4 o al 6, esos son 2 movimientos posibles, del 4 al 3 al 9 o al 0, esos son 3 movimientos y del 6 puede ir al 1, 7 o 0 lo que son otros 3 movimientos, eso va a sumar 8, que concuerda con el resultado del programa.

Que es lo que esta causando que no de el resultado total de 46 y en cambio de mas movimientos posibles que eso?

Comment: 66 = 20 + 46. ¿Estas seguro de no contar dos veces?

Comment: ¿Son validos los movimientos ciclicos? Por ejemplo, de 0->6, 6->0, 0->4 es idéntico a 0->4. ¿Cómo los cuentas?

Comment: Tambien cuento los movimientos ciclicos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No estoy seguro de haber entendido bien las condiciones del problema. En tal caso, espero tus comentarios para aclarar y corregir.

**Solución**

Primero creare una diccionario indexado por celda en el tablero. El valor son las celdas que se pueden alcanzar desde ahí:

```
movimientos = {
    0: [6, 4],
    1: [6, 8],
    2: [7, 9],
    3: [4, 8],
    4: [3, 9, 0],
    5: [],
    6: [1, 7, 0],
    7: [2, 6],
    8: [1, 3],
    9: [2, 4]
}
```

Hare una función recursiva que me ejecuta todos los movimientos válidos desde un punto de partida en un número dado de pasos (1, 2, ....)

```
def calcular(inicio, pasos):
    movs = 0
    if pasos:
        for siguiente in movimientos[inicio]:
            print(f"{pasos}: {inicio} -> {siguiente}")
            movs += 1 + calcular(siguiente, pasos - 1)

    return movs
```

El número de movimientos desde esa posición de inicio es igual al largo de la lista asociada. A eso se suman los movimientos desde cada una de las posiciones en la lista asociada, proceso que se repite recursivamente hasta completar el total de pasos.

También construyo una función que recorre cada celda de partida, computa los movimientos y los totaliza, dando el resultado final:

```
def totalizar(pasos):
    total = 0
    for i in range(10):
        total += calcular(i, pasos)
    return total
```

Para probar, calculare los movimientos en un paso y en dos pasos:

```
print(totalizar(1))
print("----")
print(totalizar(2))
```

Para validar el resultado he impreso cada movimiento contabilizado, en formato:

```
número de paso: casilla origen -> casilla destino
```

El resultado para un paso es:

```
1: 0 -> 6
1: 0 -> 4
1: 1 -> 6
1: 1 -> 8
1: 2 -> 7
1: 2 -> 9
1: 3 -> 4
1: 3 -> 8
1: 4 -> 3
1: 4 -> 9
1: 4 -> 0
1: 6 -> 1
1: 6 -> 7
1: 6 -> 0
1: 7 -> 2
1: 7 -> 6
1: 8 -> 1
1: 8 -> 3
1: 9 -> 2
1: 9 -> 4
20
```

y para dos pasos (he separado las líneas manualmente por claridad):

```
2: 0 -> 6
1: 6 -> 1
1: 6 -> 7
1: 6 -> 0

2: 0 -> 4
1: 4 -> 3
1: 4 -> 9
1: 4 -> 0

2: 1 -> 6
1: 6 -> 1
1: 6 -> 7
1: 6 -> 0

2: 1 -> 8
1: 8 -> 1
1: 8 -> 3

2: 2 -> 7
1: 7 -> 2
1: 7 -> 6

2: 2 -> 9
1: 9 -> 2
1: 9 -> 4

2: 3 -> 4
1: 4 -> 3
1: 4 -> 9
1: 4 -> 0

2: 3 -> 8
1: 8 -> 1
1: 8 -> 3

2: 4 -> 3
1: 3 -> 4
1: 3 -> 8

2: 4 -> 9
1: 9 -> 2
1: 9 -> 4

2: 4 -> 0
1: 0 -> 6
1: 0 -> 4

2: 6 -> 1
1: 1 -> 6
1: 1 -> 8

2: 6 -> 7
1: 7 -> 2
1: 7 -> 6

2: 6 -> 0
1: 0 -> 6
1: 0 -> 4

2: 7 -> 2
1: 2 -> 7
1: 2 -> 9

2: 7 -> 6
1: 6 -> 1
1: 6 -> 7
1: 6 -> 0

2: 8 -> 1
1: 1 -> 6
1: 1 -> 8

2: 8 -> 3
1: 3 -> 4
1: 3 -> 8

2: 9 -> 2
1: 2 -> 7
1: 2 -> 9

2: 9 -> 4
1: 4 -> 3
1: 4 -> 9
1: 4 -> 0

66
```

Y el resultado final es 66.

Answer (score 0):

Note que de hecho el programa si te da el reultado que buscas lo que sucede es que en la sumatoria incluye el numero de movidas de resultados anteiores, por ejemplo el resultado para dos turnos de 66 es el resultado de la suma de las 20 movidas de cuando hay un turno y las 46 de cuando hay dos turnos.
Para obtener los resultados que buscaba simplemente le restaba el resultado anterior, es decir al resultado de 5 por ejemplo, le restaba el resultado de 4.